# Can I obtain trusted SSL certificates without giving out personal information?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I am launching a site that will require secure (ssl) account login, no payments or credit cards involved. Self signed certificates gives annoying warnings in browsers, so I want to get a trusted SSL certificate from an authority. But I want to keep my personal information anonymous. Is there a major authority out there who doesn't ask for personal information, only requires some sort of proof of domain control?

Comment: Are you planning on paying with an anonymous package of cash?

Comment: Paypal is acceptable.

Comment: Trust requires trust.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with this is that the entire point of ssl is guaranteeing that you are communicating with who you think you are. If you dont disclose your identity to the issuer, how are they supposed to know you are who you say you are (ie the owner of the domain)?